# Graphical issues with overlaid ParametricPlots

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, parametric-functions

Here's my code and output:

```
(*Parametrisation of surface*)
s[a_, c_][u_, v_] := {(c + a Cos[v]) Cos[u],
   (c + a Cos[v]) Sin[u],
   a Sin[v]};

(*1D curves on the surface*)
band[a_, c_][v_] := s[a, c][0, v];
p1[a_, c_][u_] := s[a, c][u, 0];
p2[a_, c_][u_] := s[a, c][u + \[Pi], \[Pi] (1 + Erf[3 (u - \[Pi])])];

(*Setting a symbol to equal the plot graphics*)
sPlot = ParametricPlot3D[
   s[1, 2][u, v]
   , {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[{
      RGBColor[0.95, 0.95, 1, 0.7],
      Specularity[White, 10000]
      }], Mesh -> 10, MeshStyle -> Directive[{
      RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, .5, 0.8],
      Thick}]
   , PlotPoints -> 50, RotationAction -> "Clip"];

(*Displaying the final plot*)
Show[
 sPlot,
 ParametricPlot3D[{
   band[1, 2][u], p2[1, 2][u]
   }, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
  PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.05]}, {RGBColor[0.4, 0.4, 0.8], 
     Thickness[0.03]}}], PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50
 , ImageSize -> 1000
 ]
```

[image]

Now I think the problem here is pretty obvious: it looks **horrible**. The black curve is especially bad, though the blue curve also displays an issue with 'bumpiness'. Here is the kind of output I want to replicate consistently:

[image]

As you can see, the curve intersects the plot but it still looks nice. Having said that, there are still some graphical issues (look around the front-right black spot on the sphere). Here are the things I have tried to achieve the same result with the first plot:

- Increasing `PlotPoints` for all `ParametricPlot3D`s
- Tweaking the curves so they don't intersect with the surface
- Increasing `ImageSize` and shrinking the output

None of these work. The second does alleviate the problem, but it becomes very obvious that the curves don't lie on the surface.

**How can I fix this rendering/display error? At the very least, I would like to export these images to PNG without these graphical issues.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps ...

post-processing the `Line`s in the second plot in `Show` into `Tube`s:

```
plot2 = ParametricPlot3D[{band[1, 2][u], p2[1, 2][u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 50,
  PlotStyle -> {Black, RGBColor[0.4, 0.4, 0.8]}] /.  Line -> (Tube[#, .2] &); 

Show[sPlot, plot2, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using Linux by any chance? ;)

Comment: @Myridium, I am using windows 10 (64b)

Comment: Okay, I asked because of the aliasing in your image. I have that issue on Linux but not on Windows. I guess you may just have different settings. I'm interested in what happens to the directives like `Thickness` when we replace `Line` with `Tube` like this. Are there any potential side effects?

Comment: @Myridium, you need to black with the second argument of `Tube` to get the desired "thickness". I am not aware of potential side effects.